# Remove .php from example.com/test.php/foo/bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to simply remove ".php" from a url while ignoring everything after the .php

So `example.com/test.php/foo/bar` would become `example.com/test/foo/bar`

and then in the PHP template I can search for and utilize foo or bar as I please. Everything I've found to remove .php interferes with the variables at the end.

**UPDATE**: I've found some success by removing .php from the file name and then using `ForceType`. Although It'd still be nice if I could keep the .php extension so my Code Editor knows how to highlight the syntax :)

```
<FilesMatch "^test$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

**Update 2**
Here's a RewriteRule that I've tried using to some success, but when I add a trailing slash and some content after, it results in a 500 internal server error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
# remove index
    RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
# remove slash if not directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
    RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: `MultiViews` and PATH_INFO might suffice, or naming the script sans extension and using `ForceType` would as well. Else elaborate what `RewriteRule` you tried to get any advise.

Comment: I've tried several RewriteRules that all work just fine for removing .php, there's PLENTY of rules floating around that have been written for that purpose. But none of them ignore the variables I have after .php

Comment: ForceType might work. I'll look into that. Not familiar with MultiViews.

Comment: what do you mean by "ignore the variables"?

Comment: I mean ignore `/foo/bar` from `test.php/foo/bar`. In all the RewriteRules I've tried so far they remove .php ok, but then when I add a trailing slash and some content I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: So you want to have `test/foo/bar/` render `test.php?variable=foo/bar` and you want to redirect `test.php` to `test`?

Comment: no. I Want `test/foo/bar` to render to `test.php/foo/bar` I'll worry about getting the variables foo and bar in test.php, I don't need to get them with `$_GET`

Answer (score 2):

Your last block is almost there. However you need a bigger assortment of [`RewriteCond`](http://www.google.com/search?q=RewriteCond)s to make it work with an optional PATH_INFO.

Namely you need to match the word characters from the REQUEST_FILENAME/_URI first, and *then* test for existence of a like-named .php script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^/(w+)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php  -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.+)$ $1.php/$2   [L]
```

The last RewriteRule depends on existing trailing vars. Add one of the generic rule blocks for plain `http://example.com/test` requests without PATH_INFO. Note that this specific set will work with xyz.php scripts in the webroot only.

Comment: Sorry, regular expressions are very confusing to me. I've added your code underneath mine but that doesn't seem to do do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to recheck this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) ^/%1.php/%2/%3
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. And foo and bar are just example variables. I can't have them hardwritten into the htaccess file.

Comment: If `foo` and `bar` are just variables, try to recheck the edited answer above if it will giving you some tips.